# GeometryReader height differs depending on type of child view

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I want to evenly distribute arbitrary views of within a `VStack`. To do so, I wrapped the `VStack` within a `GeometryReader`. At this point, I set the height of the children of the `VStack` to an arbitrary height (10 in my case) and calculate the offset. This works as expected of children of type `Text`.

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<5) { element in
            Text("\(element)")
                .offset(y: proxy.size.height / 4 * CGFloat(element) - CGFloat(Double(element) + 0.5) * frameHeight)
                .frame(height: frameHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I want to achieve the same effect using other views (colors or rectangles for example), I manually need to subtract 32 from the height of the `GeometryReader`. The default padding of views seems to be 16 but I haven't set a padding and the same isn't true for `Text` views.

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<5) { element in
            Color.red
                .offset(y: (proxy.size.height - 32) / 4 * CGFloat(element) - CGFloat(Double(element) + 0.5) * frameHeight)
                .frame(height: frameHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case? This is just a simplified example, in my project I use a `ViewBuilder` to dynamically supply the child views.

Comment: Shortcut for future readers: The 32 pixels are added due to the default padding between views in a `VStack` of 8 pixels. In my example there are four of these paddings, resulting in 32 extra pixels in height.

Answer (score 0):

You should use spacing:

---

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    
    VStack(spacing: 0.0) {     // <<: Here!
        
        ForEach(0..<5) { element in
            Color.red
                .offset(y: (proxy.size.height - 32) / 4 * CGFloat(element) - CGFloat(Double(element) + 0.5) * frameHeight)
                .frame(height: frameHeight)
                
        }
    }
    .position(x: proxy.size.width/2, y: proxy.size.height/2)   // <<: this will Center your View!
}
.ignoresSafeArea()  // <<: this will make your View Full Screen!
```

Comment: Thanks, spacing solved the problem with the extra 32 "pixels". Do you know, why this only exists for views other than `Text`? `position` and `ignoreSafeArea()` don't seem to be necessary for my purposes.

Comment: Actually this spacing help us to less code, without it we would hard coded in every normal project, but in your case we can say to SwiftUI, we need this functionality instead of the normal one!

Comment: But why does it behave differently for `Text` and `Color` for example?

Comment: So It is Apple, they decide how they should behave, we as user just can use it, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks again for your solution but I'm still looking as to why this is the case in order to be able to generalize my view. In summary, I've learned that `VStack` by default adds padding between `Color` and `Rectangle` views but does not add padding between `Text` views. This padding by default is set to 8 pixels.